# Publish Android library to Jfrog artifactory with dependent aar file

Tags: android, maven, gradle, artifactory, android-library

I have an Android library project that contains external aar file in it. I have added aar file as a submodule instead of adding it in libs folder. So project structure is as follow:

LibraryModule
-Submodule (build.gradle, submodule.aar)

I have only two files in submodule folder one is submoudle.aar and other is build.gradle file as following:

**Submodule gradle file:**

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('submodule.aar'))
```

**Library gradle file:**

```
dependencies {
  api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  api 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
  api 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.0'
  api platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
  api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
  api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha01'

  api project(':librarymodule:submodule')
}

publishing {
 publications {
    release(MavenPublication) {
        from components.findByName('release')
        groupId = 'com.groupId '
        artifactId = 'artifactId '
        version = '0.0.4'
        artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/library-release.aar")

        pom.withXml {
            // for dependencies and exclusions
            def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
            configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://testeandroid.jfrog.io/artifactory/test/")
        credentials {
            // Use properties or environment variables for secure credential storage
            username = "test"
            password = "sadfsadfafsa"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Using above script I am able to successfully publish my library to artifactory with android dependencies such material and fragment etc as it is shown in POM file. But aar file in submodule is not published. How can i package aar file with my library on artifcatory?

Answer (score 0):

Either you import the aar as a file, by putting it into libs/, or perhaps create a fat AAR. The latter may work with your setup (https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android/)

May I ask, why are you importing an aar as a submodule?

Comment: Because not updated gradle dont allow to add aar file in libs folder while working in a library module. If we use it then while building library module's aar it throws error

Answer (score -1):

To include the AAR file from the submodule in your library project when publishing it to Artifactory, you can modify your library's Gradle script to make sure that the submodule's AAR is included as part of the publication. Here are the steps to achieve this:

Ensure that your submodule's AAR file is built and available before publishing the library. You can add a task to your library's Gradle script to copy the AAR from the submodule into your library's build directory.
In your library's build.gradle file, add the following task:

```
task copySubmoduleAar(type: Copy) {
    from project(':librarymodule:submodule').file('submodule.aar')
    into "$buildDir/submodule-aar"
}

preBuild.dependsOn(copySubmoduleAar)
```

This task will copy the AAR file from the submodule into your library's build directory.

Modify your publication configuration to include the AAR file in the publication. Update your library's build.gradle file to include the AAR file as an artifact:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
            from components.findByName('release')
            groupId = 'com.groupId'
            artifactId = 'artifactId'
            version = '0.0.4'
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/library-release.aar")
            artifact("$buildDir/submodule-aar/submodule.aar") // Include submodule AAR

            pom.withXml {
                // for dependencies and exclusions
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://testeandroid.jfrog.io/artifactory/test/")
            credentials {
                // Use properties or environment variables for secure credential storage
                username = "test"
                password = "sadfsadfafsa"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By adding `artifact("$buildDir/submodule-aar/submodule.aar")`, you include the submodule's AAR file as part of the publication.

With these modifications, when you publish your library to Artifactory, it should include both your library's AAR and the submodule's AAR in the published artifacts. Make sure to clean and rebuild your project before publishing to ensure that the latest artifacts are included.

Comment: After above implementation I get following issue
Execution failed for task ':librarysdk:publishReleasePublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'release' to repository 'maven'
   > Invalid publication 'release': multiple artifacts with the identical extension and classifier ('aar', 'null').